# run one test from suit in time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I use Pythons unittest just like in example from unittests doc. I test server aplication and it is importent for me to run each test in one time. I can not find in documentation how to do this.

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface

You can specify a specific method:

```
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

So in your case:

```
python -m unittest [FileName].TestStringMethods.test_upper
```

Comment: thank you tknickman, but this solution is very uncomfortable solution. In future I will have a lot of tests and I want run all of them but one by one, I mean when first test end secound start...